# how to delete all object Nodes in a specific namespace using open62541

Tags: opc-ua, open62541

I am writing an OPC server that needs to be configured dynamically at runtime.

I want to delete all nodes in a namespace and then add some new ones upon request.

Is there a way to delete all nodes in a namespace without having browse names of those nodes?

A functionality like:

```
UA_Server_deleteAllNodesInNamesapce(UA_Int16 nsIndex);
```

Or as an alternative, a way to discover all browse names in a namespace and then delete them one by one?